# Strange Firefox URL Encoding Behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, firefox, browser

i have a weird encoding problem in Firefox only.
I have an HTML page with character-set set to UTF-8 via

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

and most links only change the url-hash.

There is a form with some typeahead-like support, so the user can select correct values.
Some of these values contain a '&' character.

When calling .serialize() on the form i get the query string with the '&' properly escaped.

Now when i change the url-hash, everything works fine in IE and Chrome, but Firefox has some issues with this.

FF displays the '&' as '%26' when looking at the URL, but checking the parameters with Firebug i noticed it splits it into an additional parameter.

### Example

URL: `/#/Test/Index?query=foo&bar`

Firefox would display the URL as ...?query=foo%26bar, but Firebug's Parameter list would show:

`query foo`
`bar`

whereas Chrome and IE dev tools both show:

`query foo&bar`

I'm not quite sure what is causing this, I have barely found anything using Google,
especially because it is being shown correctly in the URL.

### Update

Before changing the URL hash i'm now testing if the user agent is FF.
If so, i will use `encodeURIComponent()` on the whole query string, so i get something like:
`?query%3Dfoo%26bar`  which works fine in FF, but not any other browser.

So i seem to have the choice between "encode everything and it only works in FF" and "don't encode everything and it won't work in FF but everything else".

Comment: Are you getting tripped up on how Firefox displays url encoding? Even when the url is encoded correctly, it shows the decoded text in the address bar. Try type in '%20' after your url then press enter to see what I mean.